# Android: Invalid File Error On Selected Image For AWS Upload

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a photo from image picker to AWS S3.
Here is how I get the photo into a file:

```
        @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        if (requestCode == RESULT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            imgUri = data.getData();
            imgViewPicker.setImageURI(comntImgUri);
            imgFile = new File(imgUri.getPath());
}
```

Then I pass the imgFile to this method for upload:

```
        public void uploadCommentImg(final File imgFile, String fileName, final AWSUploadListener listener) {
        TransferUtility transferUtility =
                TransferUtility.builder()
                        .context(context)
                        .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                        .s3Client(new AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance()))
                        .build(); 
        TransferObserver uploadObserver =
                transferUtility.upload("myapp-dev-images/public", imgFile.getName(), imgFile);
}
```

but I get that the file is invalid error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid file: /-1/1/content:/media/external/images/media/39/ORIGINAL/NONE/1034841947
```